# Change CSS property with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to change a CSS property with JQuery. I have already tried several examples in SO but cannot make it work.

What I have tried (numberHours is a variable defined before):

```
$(".cd-schedule .events .top-info").css("height", 1000 / numberHours + "px");
```

I also tried in 3 separate instructions, one for each css class, but it didn't work either.

This is my CSS code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .cd-schedule .events .top-info {
    display: table;
    height: 50px; /*<-- The property I want to change*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of jQuery you could use a CSS Variable (custom property) to update that value, e.g.

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyVNOL?editors=0110)

---

**CSS**

```
:root {
   --infoheight: 50px;
}

.top-info {
    display: table;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9bc;
    padding: 0;    
    height: var(--infoheight); 
    transition: height 1s 0s;
}
```

**JS**

```
let root = document.documentElement;
let numberHours = 5;

document.getElementById('btt').addEventListener('click', function() {
   root.style.setProperty('--infoheight', 1000 / numberHours + 'px')   
});
```

Comment: The answer is technically correct, but I woudln't advise to use css variables around

Comment: imho an answer should help not only OP right now, but also other people in years to come, so I think this advise could be useful anyway.

Comment: maybe worth adding a warning :)

Comment: @fcalderan Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @CristianTraìna Thanks for your comment but can you tell more details why is it not advisable? On my HTML I have a table that, depending on the number of rows, it should adapt a property on the CSS (height). What approach would be more adequate?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.myBtn').click(function(){
    $('.mydiv').css('height','100px');
});
```

```css
.mydiv{
height:50px;
width:50px;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='mydiv'></div>
<br>
<button class='myBtn'>Click to change height</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another demo with height set as floating-point-px/integer-px value and its computed css property vs. style attribute. Generally I would prefer using integer pixel values, but floats seem to work just fine. Just make sure `numberHours` is never zero.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyVzZM

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable `newHeight` just before setting height. So in you query you will use a variable instead of JS text.

```js
var numberHours = 100;
var newHeight = 1000 / numberHours + "px";
$(".cd-schedule .events .top-info").click(function () {
  $(".cd-schedule .events .top-info").css("height", newHeight);
});
```

```css
.top-info {
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cd-schedule">
  <div class="events">
    <div class="top-info"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```